# storing srings in rom on arm devices

Tags: arrays, embedded, arm

I have the following problem:

1. I've defined a array as following:
   const char const Tsk_Names[ 2 ][ 5 ] = { "LOG", "FBH" };

   The "Tsk_Names" array was mapped to the Flash (its name didn't appear in the "Entry List" section of the map file).
2. Any reference to the array caused it to be mapped to the RAM.
   e.g:

   const char* const Get_Task_Name( char cTaskId )
   {
       return ( &Tsk_Names[ 0 ][ 0 ] );
   }

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem ?

This is an example with a very small array of strings.
My real arrays are much bigger.

Comment: This is not a function of the **ARM** device, but the compiler and the options you are using (as well as the linker).  You didn't give that information, so it is difficult to help you.

Comment: I think you are mistaken in concluding it was mapped to flash because it didn't appear on the entry list; rather, when there were no references to it, it was omitted entirely.  As artless noise says, getting it mapped to flash is a function of the linker (script sections), possibly interacting with compiler keywords, pragmas, etc.